# Using [] with the Safe Navigation Operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I currently have a piece of code that looks like:

```
if match = request.path.match(/\A\/(?<slug>(?!admin|assets)\w+)/)
  match[:slug]
end
```

Is there a way to use the safe navigation operator (introduced in 2.3.0) to avoid this `if` conditional?

Comment: Use `fetch[:slug]`? Or just use safe-nav and `[]` (don't know if that'll work)? Personally I think it's hard to read already, and that'll just make it worse.

Comment: @DaveNewton can't use `fetch` here because `match` returns `nil` in the case the regex didn't match. Also open to suggestions on how to make this more readable.

Comment: I mean use `&.` then `fetch`, just like with `[]`.

Comment: `match` returns `MatchData` on success, it does not have `fetch` method like hash does

Comment: @Vasfed Ah, yep; `[]` it is then.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Just use the ordinary (non-sugar) form.

```
request.path.match(/\A\/(?<slug>(?!admin|assets)\w+)/)&.[](:slug)
```

Comment: I think the `&.[](:slug)` part is what I was doing wrong. I had previously been trying `&.[:slug]`

Comment: @KyleDecot Yep, this is what I mean with the `[]` bit although I think it's just horrendous to look at.

Answer (score 25):

For better readability I would pick `#dig` instead of the `#[]`.

Like,

```
request.path.match(/\A\/(?<slug>(?!admin|assets)\w+)/)&.dig(:slug)
```

instead of

```
request.path.match(/\A\/(?<slug>(?!admin|assets)\w+)/)&.[](:slug)
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but I get "undefined method 'dig' for MatchData", even with ruby 2.4.2 and rails 5.1.4.

Comment: The dig method is for hashes.  While it also works on arrays, it looks like MatchData doesn't fully implement the array interface.  Since the safe navigation operator works like #try! instead of #try, only the second version works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45825498

Answer (score 8):

For readability, I prefer using the match's [named_captures](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/Regexp.html#method-i-named_captures) method which is available from ruby 1.9.1, with the [safe operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) which is available from ruby 2.3.0.

```
request.path.match(/\A\/(?<slug>(?!admin|assets)\w+)/)&.named_captures&.dig('slug')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `send` any method, so using safe-browsing operator this will be:

```
request.path.match(/\A\/(?<slug>(?!admin|assets)\w+)/)&.send(:[], :slug)
```

Comment: This definitely works but I went w/ the approach of using `&.[](:slug)`. Thanks for looking into it though!